# What is the jump key?

Tags: dead-to-rights-2

I have just download Dead To Rights 2 Game but the problem is the Game is in **Russian language**.

I tried all the keys of keyboard none works, may be there is combination of keys for Jumping. Does anyone know how to jump?

Comment: Are you using a controller? Because you've tagged it in your question.

Comment: @Sean that was by mistake sorry

Answer (score 1):

I did a lot of search but all in vain , as i know the pain of searching 5 hours for just a key it is really bad.

Note : These steps are for those who are using Russian language, in English version it is a piece of cake in my eyes

**What you have to do ?**

When you Click On The Launcher.exe 
There will be options for changing keys 
First Click On Default and then Change MBUTTON to Space or any of your desired key.

That's it !